# How to solve InvalidArgumentException Route [login] not defined in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes, invalidargumentexception

I am getting **InvalidArgumentException Route [login] not defined** error here:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php

```
    /**
     * Get the URL to a named route.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  mixed   $parameters
     * @param  bool  $absolute
     * @return string
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
    {
        if (! is_null($route = $this->routes->getByName($name))) {
            return $this->toRoute($route, $parameters, $absolute);
        }

        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Route [{$name}] not defined.");
    }

    /**
     * Get the URL for a given route instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Route  $route
     * @param  mixed  $parameters
     * @param  bool   $absolute
     * @return string
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
```

This is my route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']],function(){
    route::get('/admin/dashboard','AdminController@dashboard');
});
```

This is my method:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }
    else{
        return redirect()->action('AdminController@login')->with('success','please login to access');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: run `php artisan make:auth`

Comment: Do you have a login function in your AdminController.php?

Answer (score 4):

Laravel has a `php artisan make:auth` function and if you run that in your terminal, it will generate the auth scaffolding for your application.

Check this documentation out https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication

Comment: this rout open - Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']],function(){ route::get('/admin/dashboard','AdminController@dashboard');

});' my dashboard function but it go to directly go to login function why?

Comment: That is because you are using the 'auth' middleware in your route group closure.

Answer (score 2):

Run `php artisan make:auth` to scaffold auth in your laravel app.

Answer (score 2):

Clear the view cache, that might work

Comment: Not sure if that will work but its work a shot. php artisan view:clear

Answer (score 0):

add new function on exception/handler.php

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception){
  if($request->expectsJson()){
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
  }

  return redirect('/home');
}
```